# sending sensor_msgs/CameraInfo with rosjava

Tags: ros, camera-info, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm attempting to send a sensor_msgs/CameraInfo message using rosjava. The message itself gets sent just fine, but I'd like to fill in every field of the message with my correct camera calibration information. I noticed there is a `setK()` method, as well as `setP()` and others to accomplish this task.

When I try to set those fields to some values, `rostopic echo` reports different ones.

In my code I have:

```
sensor_msgs.CameraInfo caminfomsg = caminfopub.newMessage();
double[] K = {160, 0, 160, 0, 160, 120, 0, 0, 1};
caminfomsg.setK(K);
```

But when I run it and take a look with rostopic this is what I get:

```
K: [4.4e-323, 5.337368564e-315, 0.0, 5.337368564e-315, 0.0, 5.337368564e-315, 5.33542582e-315, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35498/sending-sensor_msgs/camerainfo-with-rosjava/) by [jpiramirez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2480/jpiramirez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2012-06-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is issue 125. I should have a patch out today or tomorrow.

http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=125

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1